# Background covered on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover, cover

I would like the background to be covered on hover when you mouseover and im not sure how to get the red background to cover it on hover behind the title. I would like the title to stay fixed on the circle and the mouseover of it to be red completely behind the title with the image transparency of red to be slightly faded.

```
    <div class="view view-first">
<h2>LOGOS</h2>
<div class="mask">
  <p>The Beginning Part Of The Branding Process.Logos I Have Done For Clients</p>
  <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the CSS  on the Css I would like to have the background go behind the title

```css
.view {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #909090;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/over1.jpg");
  border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  max-width: 30.26%;
 height: 300px;
}

.view .mask,
.view .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.view h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#000000;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.view p {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
  font-family: Merriweather, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,
  1px -1px 0 #000,
  -1px 1px 0 #000,
  1px 1px 0 #000;

}

.view a.info {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*1*/

.view-first img {
  /*1*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-first .mask  {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 opacity: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,4,0.57);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 height: 100%; 
 
}

.view-first h2 {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  opacity: 100;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-first p {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-first a.info {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* */

.view-first:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view-first:hover .mask {
 display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.view-first:hover h2,
.view-first:hover p,
.view-first:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.view-first:hover p {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.view-first:hover a.info {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
      <p>The Beginning Part Of The Branding Process.Logos I Have Done For Clients</p>
      <a href="#" class="info">Click Here</a>
    </div>
```

Please let me know how I can fix this
[Html regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dGOQ.jpg)
[mouseover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPAXL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center
}

.hoverable:hover{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg" style="background: url('https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg')">

<div class="hoverable"> Hover Me </div>

</div>
```